# Tables created that I didn't ask for, is there something wrong with my Initialization Strategy in EF6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using code-first modeling with Entity Framework 6.2.0.  Part of my requirements are to assume total control over all aspects of database management, including creation, migration/update, and deletion.

To do this, I have implemented a custom initializer, like so:

```
public class MyDatabaseInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MyDataContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(MyDataContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
            Seed(context);
    }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MyDatabaseInitializer());
    }
}
```

If anyone needs details on usage, I can provide more.  But for now, I'll get right to the problem:  tables are being created in the `master` database, and I cannot figure out why.

I am not making any explicit connections to that database.  I have stepped through every bit of startup code I can, but never have I been able to catch it in the act.  I just get tables, with no evidence as to why.  I can't even spot a pattern.  It doesn't happen after any certain call, or at any particular point in the startup that I can see.  The app starts, and there they are.  Nothing in the output window, no exceptions, nothing.

I have tried:

1. Putting a breakpoint in the initial migration, where the `CreateTable` calls are made.  It was never hit, yet tables appeared in `master`.
2. Putting breakpoints in my initializer class.  Never hit.
3. Adding a `Log` output (console window) to my context.  Only shows the things I know I am doing, but never `CreateTable` calls.

I am at a loss here.  I guess I'm looking for any advice I can get...debugging tips, ways to trace/log what might be happening, maybe even ideas for why my initialization strategy might be a bad one.

**UPDATE:**

On a suggestion, I have tried placing breakpoints in the context constructors, but at the first hit, the `master` tables were already created.  In fact, at this point, I am certain that this table creation is occurring more-or-less immediately at app start, and before any of my startup code runs.  Meaning before I've created any contexts, let alone had a chance to use them.

The basic startup flow goes like this:

**App.xaml.cs** - OnStartup() sets the EF Initializer (as suggested, this is now null for testing purposes)

[MainWindow.Show() is called]

**MainWindow::OnContentRendered()** - calls the startup routine (a static method in its own class).  There is a check to ensure the startup code only executes once.

**My Startup Routine** ... by this point, the tables have already been created, and before this method does any work.

Ultimately, this has to be some baked-in thing the EF is wanting to do on its own.  But I can't find any way to intercept, or even inspect, what it's doing.  Somewhere very early on, it's wanting to create tables, and because the only DB it knows is `master`, that's where they go.  But why?  And what can I do about it?

Here's what the context and connection factories look like:

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext(new DbFactory().GetConnectionString())
{
}

public String GetConnectionString(String serverName, String databaseName)
{
    var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.DataSource = serverName;
    csb.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
    csb.ConnectTimeout = DatabaseTimeout;
    csb.PersistSecurityInfo = false;
    csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    csb.LoadBalanceTimeout = 0;
    csb.Pooling = true;
    csb.MaxPoolSize = 200;
    csb.MinPoolSize = 0;
    csb.UserInstance = false;
    csb.WorkstationID = AllMaxNetwork.MachineName;
    return csb.ConnectionString;
}

public MyDataContext(String connectionString)
    : base(connectionString) { }
```

**Another update**:
I have proven two things:

1. When these tables are created, it is using the initial migration to do so.  I changed a field length to be abnormally long, and saw that change reflected in the newly created table in `master`.
2. I placed an exception at the start of that migration, and the table creation stopped.  However, the only way that I could see evidence of that exception being thrown was to use Sysinternals' DebugView application.  Visual Studio 2017 never registered a bit of evidence that it even happened.

Unfortunately, my new knowledge only deepens the mystery.  I still have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in MyDataContext's constructor.

Comment: Do you have a web.config or app.config with a database connection in there?

Comment: Code-first, DotNet 4.5.2, WPF.  Connection string is created on-demand, not in config.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I put a breakpoint in the context's constructor, and when it was hit, I checked the `master` db.  The tables were already there.

Comment: Try adding `context.Database.Initialize(true);` to force initialization. Also, examine your connection string for clues `context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`

Comment: @SteveGreene I don't follow.  Since I never know where/when it's happening, I have no idea what I would inspect or when.  What would forcing `Initialize` do?  And I suppose same question:  when/where would I do that?

Comment: Initializers don't run until you use the context (setting the initializer does not run it), so force the issue by strategically placing `Initialize` in your startup code to force the issue.

Comment: @SteveGreene What should I be looking for then?  I'm still unclear as to what that would gain me.  Since my initializer does run when my contexts are established.  Just not (that I have seen) when this mystery instantiation happens to create the `master` tables.

Comment: So the tables created are application tables from your context, but they go into `master` instead of the intended database? Initializer should not run until you use the context or force initialization. I would suspect the connect string or perhaps configuration settings. SQL profiler may help. You say you create your connection string on demand - are your sure it is being used? Hard code one into context constructor as a test.

Comment: @SteveGreene Correct, they end up in `master`.  All connection strings are made on-demand for every context that is created.  We deal with multiple databases, and we provide a different string for each one, as needed.  I have watched both the factory and the context ctors, but I see neither a connection string, nor a `context.Database` using `master` as its DB.  I'm afraid that whatever is happening is being done by EF itself, underneath, and I can't get a breakpoint on it.

Comment: @SteveGreene Let me expand a bit for clarity:  you said "intended database".  That is not accurate.  There is no intention on my part at all.  Whatever is happening is outside the normal flow of my startup sequence.  Every part of what I _expect to happen_ does.  This is something else entirely, where a full set of tables is created in `master`, but not because of anything I deliberately attempted.  I cannot say at all what is triggering the action.

Comment: First thing I would try is setting the initializer to null. If something still changes, it is looking in you config file.

Comment: Set it null, still creates.  Only config file is the App.config in the EXE project.  All it has in it is a section `<entityFramework>` with a `<provider>` for Sql Client.

Comment: @DonBoitnott the only way for the tables to end up in `master` is if you connect to `master`. What does your connection string look like? I'll bet it contains an `Initial Catalog=master;` or no `Initial Catalog` entry at all, in which case *your account's default* database will be used. That database is defined when you create an account. If you connect as `sa` or using a DBA Windows account the default is probably `master`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I keep getting that suggestion...but what connection string?  My config file does not contain one, nor has my code has a chance to build one.  Therefore, I have no idea what connection string everyone keeps referring to.  I have no idea where I would see something that EF seems to be deriving behind-the-scenes, and all on its own.

Comment: @DonBoitnott your config file *does* contain one, otherwise it wouldn't connect to any database - which one would that be? On what machine?  EF isn't deriving anything behind the scenes

Comment: @DonBoitnott as you said earlier `All connection strings are made on-demand for every context that is created. We deal with multiple databases`. Where are those connection strings? What do they look like? What *tables* are getting generated anyway, what are their names?

Comment: @DonBoitnott in your `InitializeDatabase` method, when you call `context.Database.Exists()`, what does the connection string for `Database` look like? What does your *migration script* look like?

Comment: I added examples of the relevant pieces.  The connection string look as I would expect.  None of them have `master` in them.  All tables are being created, every table I would expect in one of my databases, the names don't seem relevant.  And the InitializeDatabase method is also irrelevant now, as I have said...there is no initializer in play, it's been set `null`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your comment about the "account's default database" is intriguing.  Let's assume that because I'm supplying no default connection string that one is being created for me, and that it's using `master` as its database.  The real question is still "why".  Why is it doing that?  What is EF doing that it needs one in the first place?  What can I do to stop it, or to at least see it?  Unless I can get to the bottom of why it's even happening, then all of this is just academic.

Comment: **What kind of tables** are you talking about? If you're using sql server, yes there will always be some tables in the master database. As it says [here:](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-system-databases-the-master-database/) SQL Server uses the master database to record all information about the SQL Server instance system, like login accounts, endpoints, linked servers and configuration settings. ... This has nothing to do with EF.

Comment: @AsheraH My tables.  Tables I defined.